# Issue with modifying objects that are added by Angular modal controller

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

I'm having issue with modifying objects that are adding through angular modal controller

I have

```
.controller("viewController", function($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.allPosts = [
    {
      id: 1,
      owner: "Owner 2",
      profile: "images/profile.png",
      title: "Book title 1",
      image: null,
      price: 25,
      reply: 2,
      fav: 1,
      isFaved: false,
      content: "test"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      owner: "Owner",
      profile: "images/profile2.png",
      title: "Ken Follett",
      image: "images/book1.jpg",
      price: 20,
      reply: 12,
      fav: 3,
      isFaved: true,
      content: "The book is in nice"
    }
  ]; 

  $scope.addFav = function(id) {
    _.each($scope.allPosts, function(post) {
      if(post.id === id) {
        post.isFaved = !post.isFaved;
        if(post.isFaved) {
          post.fav++;
          $scope.myFavs.push(post);
        } else {
          post.fav--;
          $scope.myFavs = _.reject($scope.myFavs, function(post) {
            return post.id === id;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $scope.addPost = function() {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
          allPosts: function(){
              return $scope.allPosts;
          }
      }
    });
  };
)

.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, allPosts) {
  $scope.postId = 50;
  $scope.ok = function () {

    var temp = {};
    temp.id = $scope.postId;
    temp.profile = "images/profile.png";
    temp.title = $scope.title;
    temp.type = $scope.type;
    temp.price = $scope.price;
    temp.reply = 0;
    temp.fav = 0;
    temp.isFaved = false;
    temp.content = $scope.description;
    $scope.allPosts.push(temp);
    $scope.postId++;
    $modalInstance.close();
  };    
});
```

$scope.addFav(id) function works fine with existing $scope.allPosts. However, when I add new object by using the ModalInstanceCtrl, the $scope.allPosts is updated but when it goes to $scope.addFav(id), I can not modified the new object that is pushed in to $scope.allPosts from ModalInstanceCtrl. for example I try to update the fav property in post by using

```
post.fav++; // console.log(post) shows the fav property is not updated. it remains at 0.
```

Comment: Where are you applying the new post's id ?
To me it looks like the new post doesnt get an id, so that it will never be matched in the loop id === post.id

Comment: I removed some unnecessary data to make the code easier to read. I removed the id property by mistake. It has nothing to do with the id. I added the id property now. Thanks

Comment: Both of the controllers have their own distinct $scope. The allPosts is not shared between the controllers. The usual solution is to have the common data in a service that is injected into both controllers.

Comment: How come I was able to see the newly added object from ModalInstanceCtrl in viewController? I can get all the newly added objects and display them but I can't modify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't show the markup I suspect that the ModalInstanceController must be nested within the scope of the viewController. This would explain how the same allPosts is available in both controllers. However the postId will be different on each scope due to the way that javascript's prototypical inheritance works. To overcome this you could define an object on scope something like this:

```
$scope.posts = {
    postId: 0,
    allPosts: []
}
```

Alternatively, and even better imho, define a Posts service that encapsulates all the post behaviours and inject that into both controllers. You are then insulated from any changes to the markup that could muck up the controller inheritance.